# SQLCLR - Wrapping a COM call

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

i'm trying to call a .net assembly that wraps a few COM calls (to a third party dll) from Sql Server. The assembly registers fine (i tried registering with unsafe and external access), but when i run the procedure i get this error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ManagedCodeCallTest": 
>   System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
>   System.UriFormatException: 
>      at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>      at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.RuntimeLicenseContext.GetLocalPath(String fileName)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.RuntimeLicenseContext.GetSavedLicenseKey(Type type, Assembly resourceAssembly)
>      at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.LicenseInteropHelper.GetCurrentContextInfo(Int32& fDesignTime, IntPtr& bstrKey, RuntimeTypeHandle rth)
>      at ManagedCode.MyClass.ArielComponentCall()

Any ideas? Is what i'm trying to do even possible? I read something about licensed dlls but the information was very vague.

EDIT: CLR code in case it helps:

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void ArielComponentCall()
{
    Ariel.ApplicationClass application = new Ariel.ApplicationClass();

    object arielDoc = application.OpenDocument(@"P:\Projects\COAT\Ariel1.run");
}
```

The project that contains this class has the reference to the com object.

Answer (score 2):

The SqlClr implementation on SQL Server contains [a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172338%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of "blessed" .net Assembly methods which will work within SQL Server. This is being managed through [Host Protection Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.hostprotectionattribute.aspx). More precisely

> SQL Server disallows the use of a type or member that has a
>   HostProtectionAttribute that specifies a HostProtectionResource value
>   of SharedState, Synchronization, MayLeakOnAbort, or
>   ExternalProcessMgmt. This prevents the assemblies from calling members
>   that enable sharing state, perform synchronization, might cause a
>   resource leak on termination, or affect the integrity of the SQL
>   Server process.

Depending on the "Access" settings of your assembly SQL Server will throw an error (when SAFE), or do nothing with the blocked method (`UNSAFE` and `EXTERNAL ACCESS`).

Unfortunately for you, the `System.ComponentModel.LicenseContext` class has the `SharedState` Host Protection Attribute and is part of the code which is not allowed. As a consequence, somewhere in your code there is a call to a method in the LicenseManager which will silently do nothing.

Either way, running com components within the SQL Server process is not a good idea as a crash in the com component will crash your entire SQL Server.